# How to create jspm bundle with fabric.js v2

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, jspm

I'm trying to create a javascript bundle with JSPM that includes fabric.js version 2. Alas, performing jspm bundle fails.

```
$ jspm bundle src/main --minify --inject
       Building the bundle tree for src/main...

err  Error on fetch for @empty/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils.js at file:///Users/dkoerner/projects/JSPMFabricTestCase/@empty/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils.js
    Loading npm:fabric@2.0.0-rc.4/dist/fabric.js
    Loading npm:fabric@2.0.0-rc.4.js
    Loading src/bootstrap.js
    Loading src/main.js
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/dkoerner/projects/JSPMFabricTestCase/@empty/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils.js'
```

I have created a test project (https://github.com/dkoerner85/JSPMFabricTestCase) following the jspm and fabric examples and verified that bundle creation works with the current fabric stable release v1.7.22. Raising the version to the release candidate v2.0.0-rc4 however breaks bundling.

I am fairly new to javascript app development and hence do not understand the reason why this fails and how to repair it. I am grateful for any pointers or explanation.

npm: v5.5.1
node: v8.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Add an override section to your project's `package.json`:

```
"overrides": {
  "npm:fabric@2.0.0-rc.4": {
    "map": {
      "canvas": "@empty",
      "fs": "@empty",
      "jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils": "@empty",
      "jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils": "@empty",
      "jsdom": "@empty",
      "http": "@empty",
      "https": "@empty",
      "xmldom": "@empty",
      "url": "@empty"
    }
  }
}
```

## Insight

After reading about jspm and systemJS, I have found a solution to this problem. The critical code is in the fabric.js and package.json files of the fabric package.

*dist/fabric.js*

```
...
fabric.document = require('jsdom').jsdom(decodeURIComponent('%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3C%2Fhead%3E%3Cbody%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E'),{ features: {FetchExternalResources: ['img']}});
fabric.jsdomImplForWrapper = require('jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils').implForWrapper;
fabric.nodeCanvas = require('jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils').Canvas;
fabric.window = fabric.document.defaultView;
DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
...
```

*package.json*

```
...
"browser" : {
   "canvas": false,
   "fs":      false,
   "jsdom":   false,
   "jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils": false,
   "jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils": false,
   "http":   false,
   "https":   false,
   "xmldom":  false,
   "url": false
},
...
```

Now, when installing the package with `jspm install npm:fabric@2.0.0-rc.4`, jspm will modify the require statements, resulting in the following code:

*jspm_packages/npm/fabric@2.0.0-rc.4/dist/fabric.js*

```
...
fabric.document = require('@empty').jsdom(decodeURIComponent('%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3C%2Fhead%3E%3Cbody%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E'), {features: {FetchExternalResources: ['img']}});
fabric.jsdomImplForWrapper = require('@empty/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils').implForWrapper;
fabric.nodeCanvas = require('@empty/lib/jsdom/utils').Canvas;
fabric.window = fabric.document.defaultView;
DOMParser = require('@empty').DOMParser;
...
```

When trying to create a bundle, jspm will stumble over the `'@empty/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils'` require statement.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/dkoerner/projects/JSPMFabricTestCase/@empty/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils.js'
```

jspm treated the `jsdom` entries first as required by the `package.json`, thereby failing to recognize the more detailled entry `'jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils'`. It is necessary to provide the map in the correct order - long paths before short paths.

This can be achieved with a local override as depicted in the solution above. Please note that `jsdom` is ordered below `@empty/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils` in the override, as opposed to the original `package.json`.